# Mysqldump on RDS Read Replica Slave is 50x slower

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, database-performance, database-replication

I created a read-replica of my MySQL database on amazon RDS.

When executing the following command, it is super fast (half a second) on the master, but takes more like 30 seconds on the slave.  Super annoying because I wanted to dump off of the slave so that I don't slow down the master.

```
mysqldump --set-gtid-purged=OFF -h myDomain.com -u dev -pmyPassword mySchema > out.sql
```

Comment: Are the master and slave in the same data center? Maybe the network connection to the slave is slower.

Comment: the master is in Ohio, the slave is in California.  A server in California performs a dump VERY fast.  Also, when I pipe the dump through the california server, it is very fast.  So why is it that if I dump directly from the California slave it is slow??

Comment: Where are you executing the mysqldump?

Comment: I'm executing the mysqldump locally, in Texas

Comment: Could be a network latency issue. You can verify this by doing a traceroute from your Texas location to both the master and the slave.

Comment: If all the tables in your schema are InnoDB, you can add the `--single-transaction` option and your mysqldump won't block anything. It will start a transaction so it has a consistent snapshot of the database. Meanwhile other uses of your database will continue while the dump is running. So you can dump from whichever instance is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues to consider.

The most significant is that `mysqldump` does not perform well when run at a distance from the database, due to limitations in the traditional MySQL client/server wire protocol, which makes no allowance for pipelining a series of commands.

The `mysqldump` utility uses no magic to generate dump files -- it issues SQL statements to the server, and takes the results of those queries to generate its output.

As a result, every single object (schema, table, view, stored function/procedure, event) in the database requires at least one round trip and sometimes more than one.

For each table, `mysqldump` first issues `SHOW CREATE TABLE t1;` followed by `SELECT * FROM t1;` ... so a round trip time of 100 ms would mean that extracting a dump file of 150  tables would mean 150 × 2 × 0.100 = 30 seconds are simply wasted by the distance between the machine running `mysqldump` and the server -- and this is true even if the tables are completely empty.

This is **not** a recommendation, but you might take a look at [mydumper](https://github.com/maxbube/mydumper), which claims to have the ability of creating the backup using multiple database connections, in parallel, and this could help mediate the cycles wasted as commands pass to the server and return to the client, by parallelizing the dump process.  I don't know the quality of this code base, but something like this could help.

---

Next, you almost always want to use the `--compress` option for `mysqldump`.  Contrary to what you might assume, this **does not** compress the backup file.  The generated backup file is identical when this option is used, but when this feature is activated, the server compresses the data it sends to `mysqldump` on the wire, and `mysqldump` decompresses the data again before writing it out -- so this option will almost always make for a faster process unless the machine running `mysqldump` and the database server are connected by a low-latency, high-bandwidth network.  Because the generated file is identical, there are no compatibility concerns when using this option.

---

Finally, there's an issue with newly-created RDS servers that you need to be aware of, so that it doesn't skew your benchmarks.  When you create an RDS replica, it is originally seeded with data from a snapshot of the upstream master.  This is, behind the scenes, an EBS snapshot of the master's hard drive, and the new database instance is backed by an EBS volume restored from that snapshot.  EBS volumes are lazily-loaded from the snapshot, so they have a documented first-touch penalty.  This issue could have a substantial impact on the performance of the first complete backup, but should have no meaningful impact after that.

Comment: Where did you get this from, that MySQL protocol does not support pipelining? A compatible implementation *must* support pipelining, if only to make closing prepared statements possible.  COM_STMT_CLOSE is sent to the server, and there is no reply. So, let's say you want to close a  prepared statement, then do something else, e.g send COM_QUERY, then you'll be sending multiple commands without waiting for server reply for each command. It is called pipelining. There are buggy  protocol implementations, that *discard* client data, like Amazon Aurora, but this is called a bug in implementation.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub I don't recall exactly what I was thinking when I wrote this, but it seems like it was intended as an oversimplification.  There is no *explicit* support for sequential pipelined `COM_QUERY` operations -- the server just remains blissfully unaware of the as-yet-unexecuted queries sitting in the incoming buffer until it's ready to look for the next one -- and there's no escape hatch if an error occurs, because the next query that was sent would just be read and executed whether the client would have wanted that or not.

Comment: There are 2 drivers known to me that use pipelining that both have to workaround Aurora bugs by disabling it, and they document how to. One is MariaDB's  JDBC driver,

Comment: JDBC documents Aurora pipelining issue in https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-477, and in other places in documentation, another one is MySqlConnector.NET, which documents Aurora bug in https://mysqlconnector.net/troubleshooting/aurora-freeze/. Apparently, pipelining is useful, there is implicit support. and it appears to work, except Aurora which decided to discard user input.  As for reducing roundtrips the old good batching with semicolons "command;command" already would do pretty good. it is not as seamless as pipelining, but for mysqldump purposes sufficient.